# Finding taylor series expansion of Zeta function around $z=2$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $C(z) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^z} $. I want to find the Taylor series of $C(z)$ around $z = 2 $. I know that

$$ C'(z) = - \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \log n \frac{1}{n^z} $$

But, how can I find the $nth$ derivative of $C(z) $ ?

Comment: Each time you take another derivative of $n^{-z}$, you just multiply by another factor of $-\log n$. The hard part is going to be evaluating the series at $z=2$.

Comment: Is there a closed for for $$\sum_{n\geq1}  \frac{ (-1)^n (\log n)^k }{z^2}$$?

Comment: I meant closed form*

Comment: What you have written is probably not what you meant. You want that $z$ to be $n$, right? If so, then I don't know the answer for certain, but I'd be pessimistic.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**. You may prove that,
$$
\left.\partial_z^{p}\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^z}\right)\right|_{z=2}=\left.\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(e^{-z\ln n}\right)^{(p)}\right|_{z=2}=\left.\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}  \frac{(-\ln n)^p}{n^z}\right|_{z=2}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}  \frac{(-\ln n)^p}{n^2}.
$$