# Taylor Series of $\zeta(s)$ at $s=2+0i$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

First, I'd like to recognize that there is a very similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1520361/finding-taylor-series-expansion-of-zeta-function-around-z-2). However, I think my question is a little different, as I believe that it goes into a little more depth, so I believe this question doesn't go against the sitewide rules for duplicate questions.

Now, I was trying to find the Taylor Series of $\zeta(s)$ centered about 
$s=2+0i$, as the function is analytic everywhere, and I arrived at

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\zeta^{(n)}(2)}{n!}(s-2)^n$$

which, when expanded, looks something like

$$
\frac{\sum_{a=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{a^2}}{0!}(s-2)^0+
\frac{\sum_{b=0}^{\infty}-\frac{\ln{b}}{b^2}}{1!}(s-2)^1+
\frac{\sum_{c=0}^{\infty}\frac{\ln^2{c}}{c^2}}{2!}(s-2)^2+
...$$
Expanding these three series further, we obtain

$$\frac{1}{1^2*0!}(s-2)^0+\frac{1}{2^2*0!}(s-2)^0+\frac{1}{3^2*0!}(s-2)^0+...$$
$$+$$
$$\frac{-\ln{1}}{1^2*1!}(s-2)^1+\frac{-\ln{2}}{2^2*1!}(s-2)^1+\frac{-\ln{3}}{3^2*1!}(s-2)^1+...$$
$$+$$
$$\frac{\ln^2{1}}{1^2*2!}(s-2)^2+\frac{\ln^2{2}}{2^2*2!}(s-2)^2+\frac{\ln^2{3}}{3^2*2!}(s-2)^2+...$$

If we take these infinite series and instead sum them as *columns,* instead of rows, (the rearrangement of which I believe is justified by the absolute convergence of each of the series individually) we obtain

$$\frac{1}{1^2}\sum_{d=0}^{\infty}\frac{\ln^d{\frac{1}{1}}}{d!}(s-2)^d+
\frac{1}{2^2}\sum_{f=0}^{\infty}\frac{\ln^f{\frac{1}{2}}}{f!}(s-2)^f+
\frac{1}{3^2}\sum_{g=0}^{\infty}\frac{\ln^g{\frac{1}{3}}}{g!}(s-2)^g+...$$
which WolframAlpha recognizes as
$$\frac{1^{2-s}}{1^2}+\frac{2^{2-s}}{2^2}+\frac{3^{2-s}}{3^2}+...$$
which collapses to
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^{2-s}}{n^2}$$
which, unfortunately, collapses to
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^s}=\zeta(s).$$

Furthermore, when I use this method to try to analytically extend $\zeta(s)$ to $\Re(s)<1$ my calculations are completely incorrect. What am I doing wrong? I am very new to complex analysis, and I know that my manipulations are certainly not rigorous, but I don't see what I mucked up.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a singularity for the zeta function at $s=1$, so that means that a Taylor expansion around $s=2$ will have a radius of convergence $R\leq 1$, since polynomials cannot represent poles and the domain of convergence of the Taylor series is always a circle around the point of expansion, provided that the function is analytic around it. Basically the representation chosen for $\zeta(s)$ has a limited radius of convergence and that persists throughout the calculation, even though the resummation procedure that was used seems to have an infinite radius of convergence since it is a sum of exponentials. In order to analytically extend  $\zeta(s)$ to the whole complex plane, a different procedure is required. For an extension of the radius of convergence refer to the Wikipedia article [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function#Dirichlet_series). In the same article, a functional equation that connects $\zeta(s)$ and $\zeta(1-s)$ is mentioned, which can in turn be used to analytically continue the function everywhere.

Comment: I understand that the radius of convergence should be 1, and the taylor series found should be defined on (1,3], but I the Taylor series I found is defined for s in (1, infinity). I don't understand exactly why that is, however.

Comment: It is not, you started from a summation that is defined in (1,3] and therefore subsequent manipulations of the relation will have to be restricted in (1,3] to be true.

Comment: I see. Thanks for your help!